# Как настроить IntelIJ IDEA Educational на использование Java EE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee, установка

Нужно изучить `JSP`, которые входят в `java EE`. Пытаюсь настроить `intelij-idea educational edition` на использование этой технологии. Скачал для изучения [Java EE 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGYsa.png) (SE 8 тоже установил). Как я понял, в архиве находится сервер для проверки сервлетов.

При создании проекта нужно прописать путь к JDK, что я и сделал, но возможности создавать `jsp` так и не получил. Добавить шаблоны вручную тоже не могу.

Мне казалось, что Educational Edition это полная версия IDE с ограничением времени использования на 4 года и она поддерживает использование Java EE.

Помогите настроить среду разработки. Спасибо. Прикрепляю скриншоты из `intelIJ`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак. Она не поддерживает `Java EE`. Вам нужна `Ultimate` версия. Если в списке нет технологий - значит версия программы не поддерживает их. Настраивать ничего там не надо

Comment: @Tsyklop Какую среду разработки тогда использовать? Eclipce подойдет?

Comment: @Tsyklop не надо вводить в заблуждение Educational Edition - это всего лишь разновидность лицензии - она распространяется и на Ultimate версию [пруфлинк](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/) - лицензия позволяет вести разработку на Java EE

Comment: А что вы вообще понимаете под поддержкой? Так то Java EE поддерживает и блокнот.

Comment: @Tankred мне бы хотелось иметь возможность создавать jsp-проекты, запускать проекты из среды, видеть подсветку тегов и т.д.

Comment: Давайте по порядку: JSP это технология-шаблонизатор. Понятия "JSP-проект" не существует, вы просто можете подключить эту технологию к любому веб-проекту и в зависимости от стека технологий - у вас будет разная конфигурация. Запуск из среды - такой же как и у любого веб приложения. Подсветка текста и подсказки? Ну так этот функционал обеспечивается XML редактором на основе схем которые вы указываете в самом начале страницы. То есть это может вообще любой редактор включая бюджетную версию идеи.

Comment: @Tankred я не правильно выразился. Я не могу подключить JSP к своему проекту. Возможности создать jsp-файл или web-приложение из intelIJ IDEA у меня нет. Хотя в этом видео-уроке https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hk4rzwH9-kY у автора есть возможность создавать jsp-файлы из IDEA

Comment: Ох уж эти уроки на ютуб. Вы можете создать просто файл с расширением jsp, что будет тем же самым. Если хотите чтобы один в один как на видео - вам нужна ультимейт версия Идеи, хотя честно говоря реальной разницы в кол-ве действий нет.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Можете использовать `IDEA Ultimate` версию

Comment: @BarmaleysupportsMonica и что там? У человека не так версия. Если бы `Educational Edition` поддерживала Java EE, то можно было бы создать проект + спринговые проекты, как это в `Ultimate` версии. То что входии в лицензию это одно, а то что у человека не та версия Идеи это совсем другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimate версия будет работать месяц, так что, в образовательных целях её вполне хватит. Потом она будет выключаться каждые 30 минут, что тоже приемлемо. Её можно удалять и устанавливать заново, получая ещё месяц.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же пишут, что Early Access версии тоже имеют полную функциональность, и живут месяц.

Answer (score 0):

Надо включить/скачать плагин Java EE.

Читайте [документацию](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html), а не видео youtube:

> For the JavaEE Application option and associated features to be available:
>   The Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets plugin must be enabled

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, у вас есть ученическая лицензия JetBrains. С её помощью, с сайта JatBrains вы можете скачать IntellijIDEA Ultimate Edition, которая поддерживает разработку на JavaEE. Больше информации о лицензии на официальном сайте https://www.jetbrains.com/student/